# How to check a datetime duration exists in another datetime duration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails application for Examination management.

Exams can be created for a time period.

`Exam` model have the fields `start_date:datetime` and `end_date:datetime`

Exam creation is a 2 step process. In the first step all the exam details including `start_date` and `end_date` is given.

In the second step I want to list all exams that have a conflicting time period with the current exam so that the user can choose whether to continue or not.

Example:

Current exam:

```
Start date and time: "2015-02-23 10:30:00"

End date and time: "2015-02-23 13:30:00"
```

Conflicting exam:

```
Start date and time: "2015-02-23 12:30:00"

End date and time: "2015-02-23 14:30:00"
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to check if there is no conflict, then preface with `!`. There's no conflict, obviously, if one exam starts after the other ends, or ends before the other starts.

I've assumed there's no conflict if one exam starts at the same time another ends, but it's a simple change if that's considered a conflict. I've also assumed there's no time-travel (i.e., exams ending before they begin).

```
require 'time'

def conflict?(exam1, exam2)
  !(Time.parse(exam1.last)  <= Time.parse(exam2.first) ||
    Time.parse(exam1.first) >= Time.parse(exam2.last))
end

conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-23 12:30:00", "2015-02-23 14:30:00"])
  #=> true
conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-23 12:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"])
  #=> true
conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 12:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-23 12:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"])
  #=> false
conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 12:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-24 12:30:00", "2015-02-24 13:30:00"])
  #=> false
```

**Edit:** come to think of it, because of the date-time string format employed, it's not necessary to parse the strings. For example:

```
"2015-02-23 10:30:00" <= "2015-02-23 12:30:00"
  #=> true
```

We have:

```
def conflict?(exam1, exam2)
  !(exam1.last <= exam2.first || exam1.first >= exam2.last)
end

conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-23 12:30:00", "2015-02-23 14:30:00"])
  #=> true
conflict?(["2015-02-23 10:30:00", "2015-02-23 12:30:00"],
          ["2015-02-23 12:30:00", "2015-02-23 13:30:00"])
  #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass other exam `conf` objects `to overlaps` method. It will return the array of conflicting exam objects

```
conf_array = []
def overlaps(conf)
    conf_array << conf if  (start_date - conf.end_date) * (conf.start_date - end_date) >= 0
end
```

or

```
conf_array = []
def overlaps(conf)
    conf_array << conf if ((start_date..end_date).cover?(conf.start_date) || (start_date..end_date).cover?(conf.end_date))
end
```

or

```
conf_array = []
def overlaps(conf)
    conf_array << conf if ((start_date..end_date).include_with_range?conf.start_date || (start_date..end_date).include_with_range?conf.end_date )
end
```

Comment: It wont work in scenario mentioned by @RustamA.Gasanov

Comment: why second block will not work, if current period 2..3 and conflicting period 1..4, so (start_date..end_date).cover?(conf.start_date) will return true and (start_date..end_date).cover?(conf.end_date) will return false and I am ORing the result, so it will be true. It should work right?

Comment: try now I updated with brackets and pipe symbol and also added third way to try

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an attribute named **exam_time_range**

```
def exam_time_range
  start_date..end_date
end
```

another method for checking conflicts

```
def time_conflict?(time)
  exam_time_range.cover?(time) || time.cover?(exam_time_range)
end
```

And last but not least, the method that holds the logic

```
def list_all_conflicts
  Exam.find_each do |exam|
    if time_conflict?(exam.start_date..exam.end_date)
      exam
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It wont work in scenario mentioned by @RustamA.Gasanov

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in a single AR query? Something like the one below, but it can definitely be written more elegantly.

```
# whatever u want
e = Exam.first 

# Where start between e.start , e.end
# Or end between e.start , e.end
# And != e
Exam.where('start_date between datetime(?) and datetime(?) 
OR end_date between datetime(?) and datetime(?)', 
e.start_date, e.end_date, e.start_date, e.end_date)
.where.not(id: e.id)
```